# PHP get letter id from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array:

```
$arr = array(c,b,a);
```

And another array:

```
$string = array(a,a,b);
```

How to do to it give me a array looks like there:

```
$arr2 = array(2,2,1);
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what have u tried so far

Comment: What is it - `3,3,2`?

Comment: What's the logic behind it?

Comment: 3,3,2 is a number of letters in first array

Comment: Then what is second array for?

Comment: yes, not 3,3,2 but 2,2,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `array_search()` could solve the problem, but remember `array_search()` will return FALSE if it does not find the value in the array

```
$arr = array('c','b','a');
$string = array('a','a','b');
$new_arr = array();

foreach ( $string as $value){
    $index = array_search($value, $arr);
    if ( $index !== false ) {
        $new_arr[] = $index;
    } else {
        $new_arr[] = -1;    // used -1 to indicate a NO FIND
    }
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you can use  array_keys()

```
foreach($string as $key => $value){
   array_search($value, array_keys($arr));

}
```

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$arr = array('c','b','a','d');
$string = array('a','a','b');
$op=array();
foreach($string as $value)
{
    $op[]=array_search($value, $arr);
}
print_r($op)
?>
```

**Output-**

> Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 )

Comment: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$arr = array('c','b','a');

$string = array('a','a','b');

$res = [];

foreach ($string as $arr_val){
   $res[] = ((int)array_search($arr_val, $arr))+1;
}

print_r($res);
```